# React-Native Android Spinner

Tags: android, react-native, spinner, overlay, loader

I am working on displaying loader using library 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'
It is working fine on marshmallow device but on lollipop it is just displaying the overlay, no spinner is getting displayed. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make something up to replace it using [ActivityIndicator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html) and StyleSheet.absoluteFill.